# Cannot access Vue Router Current Parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

In my initial App.vue I'm dispatching an action that checks the authentication of a user. The component looks as follows:

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <spinner v-if="!user" :status="spinner.status" :color="spinner.color" :size="spinner.size" :depth="spinner.depth" :rotation="spinner.rotation" :speed="spinner.speed"></spinner>
            <div v-if="style">
            <app-header></app-header>
            <v-content style="margin-left:24px;margin-right:24px;">
                <!-- <v-container grid-list-md text-cs-center> -->
                    <router-view v-if="user"></router-view>
                <!-- </v-container> -->
            </v-content>
            <app-footer></app-footer>
        </div>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

In this component I add the  component. This will render as soon as we know the auth status.

Once the auth status has been determined (logged in/out) I dispatch another action which is responsible for fetching styles from the server. The admin user gets a generic style while a normal user would get a styling based on a dynamic value in the URL.

Eg: yoursite.com/company_one would fetch styles from the server where the company is **company_one**

When I try to access the router in my store.js file I receive the following output in the console.

`console.log(router.history)` => [image]

I now want to drill down to get the agency parameter so I try:

If I
    console.log(router.history.current); 
Which gives me the following output in the console:
[image]

All of the sudden all properties are empty. If I drill further to get to the agency, the console outputs **undefined**

Can somebody explain why this happens?

Comment: Any example to reproduce on jsfiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the current params, you can try `this.$route.params` like described here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html